# Can you extend an inner class in Kotlin, without extending it's outer class?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, inner-classes, extending-classes

In Java you can do this:

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
    }
}

class ExtendedClass extends Outer.Inner{
    ExtendedClass(Outer outer) {
        outer.super();
    }
}
```

So I'd expect in Kotlin you write something like this:

```
class ExtendedClass(outer: Outer): Outer.Inner(outer: Outer) {
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

I know you can do this:

```
class ExtendedOuter: Outer() {
    inner class ExtendedInner: Inner(){
    }
}
```

but this forces you to extend the Outer Class which is not always desirable.

This brings me to the question:

Can you extend an inner class in Kotlin, without extending it's outer class? If not, why are we allowed to declare non-open outer classes, when they contain an open inner class?

Comment: You can extend an open inner class inside its non-open outer class as another inner class. Mostly likely they don’t support the first case you described because it is so rarely needed and violates the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't find any references on how to extend an inner class inside a non-open outer class. Unfortunately IntelliJ's context actions for this specific case result in invalid code. Would you mind showing an example?

Comment: I just mean this: `class Outer { open inner class Inner; inner class ExtendedInner: Inner() }`